# WebSQL - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, web-sql

I want to make an app with `Phonegap`, but I have problems with the `Web SQL` coding.
The app is very simple: button1 to pick current time and set on value1, then button1 pick current time again and set to value2; a field to identificate the activity and after all fields are filled, button1 again to open a dialog box to OBS, and then open a new page with all activities:

```
// JavaScript Documentvar db;
var dbCreated = false;

/*var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
 vScrollbar : false,
 hScrollbar : false,
 hScroll : false
}); */
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var ativ = document.getElementById("ativ").value;
var hi = document.getElementById("hi").value;
var hf = document.getElementById("hf").value;
var obs = document.getElementById("obs").value;

function onDeviceReady() {

    db = openDatabase("RegistrationDB", "1.0", "Registration", 1024 * 1024);
    if (dbCreated) {
    } else {
        db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
    }
}

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RegistrationDB');
    var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RegistrationDB ( " + " atividade, " + " horaInicial, " + " horaFinal, " + " observacao)";
    tx.executeSql(sql);
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO RegistrationDB (atividade, horaInicial, horaFinal, observacao) VALUES ('" + ativ + "','" + hi + "' , " + hf + ", '" + obs + "')");

}

function transaction_error(tx, error) {
    alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success() {
    dbCreated = true;

    // where you want to move
    alert("Successfully inserted");
    window.location="tela2.html";
}// JavaScript Document
```

Comment: it's not clear what is the problem. If you have some unwanted behavior you can think to call executeSql with the error (and success) callback, too.

Comment: So what is exactly your problem?

Comment: well.. this code doesn't work... that's my problem.
I get this message: 

"Database error: Undefined"

Comment: have you tried declaring "db" as a variable?